# Beginner's scoring system

Tags: python, scoring

```
from time import sleep
total = 0

def calcu():
    import random
    num1 = random.randint(1,20)
    
    import random
    num2 = random.randint(1,100)
    
    sum = num1 + num2
    answer = int(input("What Is " + str(num1) + " + " + str(num2) + " = "))
    
    if answer == sum:
        print("Correct\n")
        sleep(3.00)
        total = total + 1
        calcu()
    else:
        print("Incorrect The Correct Answer Is " + str(sum) + "\n")
        sleep(3.00)
        print(total)

calcu()
```

How do I add a scoring system to the loop without resetting the score back to 0? sorry bad grammar, also new to this...

p.s got the answer

total = 0

def calcu(total):

```
import random
num1 = random.randint(1,20)

import random
num2 = random.randint(1,20)

sum = num1 + num2
answer = int(input("What Is " + str(num1) + " + " + str(num2) + " = "))

if answer == sum:
    print("Correct\n")
    sleep(3.00)
    total = total + 1
    calcu(total)
else:
    print("Incorrect The Correct Answer Is " + str(sum) + "\n")
    sleep(3.00)
    print(total)
```

calcu(total)

Comment: What do you mean by a scoring system? What should the score be reset to instead?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and note well that this is **not a discussion forum**. We need a much more **specific** description of a problem, not "create a scoring system" - that could mean countless different possible things.

Comment: your score is reset because you run it every time. the computer read a program from top to bottom, from left to right. ofc every time you run the program, the `total` will be 0. also, you only need to import once

Comment: @dimaskrisrianto : The code as provided in the question fails with `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'total' referenced before assignment`, so there is no chance to reset the score at all because `total` isn't set to 0 in the `def calcu()` function. Your statement *your score is reset because* is in this context pointless.

Comment: @Claudio you're right. I miss it.

Answer (score 1):

*How do I add a scoring system to a loop without resetting the score to 0?*

Define the `total` as a global value in:

```
def calcu():
    global total
```

Comment: IMO. This is a bad practice. instead, the solution can be to put the `total` variable on `def calcu(total)` so you need to pass the `total` variable and then return the `total` variable. But yeah. Your solution is the simplest solution

Comment: @dimaskrisrianto : yes, but in addition to what you suggest as a good practice would be here to actually use a loop within the function instead of a recursive function call as a loop substitute.